# File renaming using php

Tags: php, opendir

Have the following script.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('files/')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = str_replace("SKU#","",$fileName);
        rename(fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle); } ?>
```

my script is in the root directory of iss.

```
inetpub/wwwroot
```

And I am trying to as a result access the folder files/, which is one level up to wwwroot. Where contains one image called:

```
"WV1716BNSKU#.zoom.1"
```

I am using a windows OS, any idea why this is not working, code looks file.

Comment: may be you wanted `>>>$<<<fileName` inside `rename(..)` ?

Comment: Define "not working". Have you tried debugging what is working and what isn't? Does a single `rename` work without loop?

Comment: I think when its not working you should get an error. Have enabled all your error_reporting?

Comment: The file is not being renamed. Ok seems as though, it has found the directory, but it is not renaming the file. What is ">>>$<<<"?

Comment: Ok changed rename($fileName, $newName); from rename(fileName, $newName); - no luck

Comment: Is it working when you do it in the same folder?

Comment: What about same folder using `opendir('./')`

Comment: Ok here are the errors in the php log:
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(.,.) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(..,..) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(WV1716BNSKU#.zoom.1.jpg,WV1716BN.zoom.1.jpg) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error do you get? Make sure PHP is setup to display all errors.

Your script will also have to be in the same folder as your files you want to rename as all your paths are relative.

Try this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('./')){

    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))){
        $newName = str_replace("SKU#", "", $fileName);
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Ok here are the errors:
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(.,.) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(..,..) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10
[17-Jul-2012 13:19:00] PHP Warning:  rename(WV1716BNSKU#.zoom.1.jpg,WV1716BN.zoom.1.jpg) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\rename.php on line 10

Comment: You don't appear to have the rights to rename files. try changing the CHMOD value to 777 in your FTP client.